# Why is USB keyboard report format not working according to the standard defined?

Tags: keyboard, usb, stm32

I have a STM32 demo board and I trying to configure it as a USB keyboard.
I am developing it for an RTOS host system.

This is the keyboard IN report format according to the standard.

```
`unsigned char hid_report[8];
 hid_report[0]=0xE1;//E1 is scan code for shift modifier key
 hid_report[1]=0x00;//reserved
 hid_report[2]=0x04;//04 is scan code for 'a'/'A'
 hid_report[3]=0x00;
 hid_report[4]=0x00;
 hid_report[5]=0x00;
 hid_report[6]=0x00;
 hid_report[7]=0x00;`
```

But if I send this to RTOS host,the system gets hanged.I tried it on Windows and the SHIFT key doesn't seem to be working.

On the other hand if I send the report as

```
 unsigned char hid_report[8];
`hid_report[0]=0x00;
 hid_report[1]=0x00;//reserved
 hid_report[2]=0xE1;//E1 is scan code for shift modifier key
 hid_report[3]=0x04;//04 is scan code for 'a'/'A'
 hid_report[4]=0x00;
 hid_report[5]=0x00;
 hid_report[6]=0x00;
 hid_report[7]=0x00;`
```

In RTOS it seems to be working fine(Capital 'A' is being sent).But in Windows SHIFT key still doesn't work.

Anybody knows why is it behaving differently for two different OS and Why is it not working according to the standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the USB HID document, although scan codes (E0-E7) are defined for modifier keys, while using them in first byte of the report reserved for them, they should be sent as bit map and not as a array data.

So instead of sending E1 in the first byte of keyboard report, 0x02(0000 0010) should be sent.

This solved the problem